# sveltekit: change +layout in response to button click in +page

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

would have thought this would be a pretty simple thing to do but I can't figure it out. Basically, I want a property in the layout eg. `theme` in the example below, to be changed by a button click in the `+page.svelte` file

```html
<!-- +layout.svelte -->
<script lang=ts>

    let theme="light"

</script>

<div data-theme={theme}>
    <slot/>
</div>
```

I have tried creating a `+layout.ts` file with the following contents and importing in both `+page.svelte` and `+layout.svelte` and calling the toggle function in a button in the `+page.svelte` file.

```js
export function load() {
    const options = ['light', 'dark'];

    let current = 'light';

    const toggle = () => {
        console.log(current);
        current = current === 'light' ? 'dark' : 'light';
    };

    return {
        toggle,
        current
    };
}
```

This does call the toggle function as it is logged in the console but it does not update the layout using `<div data-theme={data.current}>`. This suggests to me that load is being called seperately by `+page.svelte` and `+layout.svelte` or that `+layout.svelte` is not updating despite variable changing. Is there a way to achive what I am trying to do?

**Edit: minimal reproduction**

create a new skeleton sveltekit project and modify following files

```html
<!-- src/routes/+layout.svelte -->
<script lang=ts>
    import '../app.postcss';
    import type { PageData } from './$types';

    export let data: PageData;
</script>

<div>
    {data.current}
    <slot />
</div>
```

```js
// src/routes/+layout.ts
export function load() {
    const options = ['light', 'dark'];

    let current = 'light';

    const toggle = () => {
        console.log(current);
        current = current === 'light' ? 'dark' : 'light';
    };

    return {
        toggle,
        current
    };
}
```

```html
<!-- src/routes/+page.svelte -->
<script lang=ts>
    import { page } from '$app/stores';
    import type {PageData} from './$types';

    export let data: PageData;
</script>

<h1>Welcome to SvelteKit</h1>
<p>Visit <a href="https://kit.svelte.dev">kit.svelte.dev</a> to read the documentation</p>

<div class="container">
    <button on:click={data.toggle}>Button</button>
</div>
```

start the app and click the button. The text in that `div` does not change but the the changing value appears in the console.

Comment: Would be great if you shared minimal reproduction of issue you encounter using https://node.new/sveltekit for example

Comment: updated with minimal example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a context+store for this.

On you layout, you can have:

```html
<script lang=ts>
    import { writable } from 'svelte/store';
    import { setContext } from 'svelte';

    const theme = writable('light');
    setContext('theme', theme);
</script>

<div data-theme={theme}>
    <slot/>
</div>
```

Then, on your page, you can do like this:

```html
<script lang=ts>
    import { page } from '$app/stores';
    import type { PageData } from './$types';
    import { getContext } from 'svelte';

    export let data: PageData;

    const theme = getContext('theme');
</script>

<h1>Welcome to SvelteKit</h1>
<p>Visit <a href="https://kit.svelte.dev">kit.svelte.dev</a> to read the documentation</p>

<div class="container">
    <button on:click={() => { theme.set('dark'); }}>Button</button>
</div>
```

You can also pass a toggle function instead. In your layout:

```js
let theme = 'light';
setContext('theme', () => {
    theme = theme === 'light' ? 'dark' : 'light';
});
```

And in your page:

```js
const toggle = getContext('theme');

toggle();
```